# Sandbox MacOS command line tool

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, code-signing, code-signing-entitlements

I try to build a sandboxed MacOS command line tool on Mojave 10.14.6 in Xcode 11.2. It is just a simple single target tool printing **Hello World** to stdout.

When I add the capability **App Sandbox** to the target, the tool will still be built but fail to run. When run in Xcode, in the debugger I will see the error in the context of code that tries to initiate the sandbox:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

When I run the tool from the command line, I get

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Using `codesign -d --entitlements - ./HelloWorldCli` to list the entitlements, I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
<true/>
```

Now the question: Is it possible to create a MacOS command line tool in sandbox mode? Does it even make sense? If yes, what do I have to change to apply the **App Sandbox** capability? If not, why is there the prominent option to apply the **App Sandbox** capability to a command line tool project? And what options do I have then to add entitlements like keychain-access to a command line tool in Xcode?

Comment: Hey, that's a great question. Have you been able to make progress on it?

Comment: @DevShark alas no, we made no progress on this. what we wanted to do was accessing the secure enclave from a scripted authentication process. in the end we resorted to writing a mac application and run it in background mode to sign authentication challenges. any help here will still be highly appreciated.